# How to to prove that $\vdash p\rightarrow\Box\Diamond p$ in a system where $R$ is symmetric in non-classical logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am studying non-classical logic. I want to prove that $\vdash p\rightarrow\Box\Diamond p$ in a system where $R$ is symmetric

1. $\neg(p\rightarrow\Box\Diamond p),w_i$ from $R_{\neg}$
2. $p,w_i$ from $R_{\neg}$ on 1
3. $\neg \Box\Diamond p,w_i$ from $R_{\neg}$ on 1
4. $\Diamond\neg\Diamond p,w_i$ from $R_{\neg\Box}$ on 3
5. $w_iRw_j$ from $R_\Diamond$ on 4 ?

I didn't get this fifth step ...

Comment: The [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Basic_definitions) for modal logic says: $w \Vdash \diamond A$ iff $u \Vdash A$ for some $u: wRu$. This, it seems that the proof in step 5 is "choosing" a $w_j$ such that $w_iRw_j$ where $w_j \Vdash \lnot \diamond p$.

Comment: Modal logic is far from the only "non-classical" logic. Also, "classical" often refers to the validity of the law of excluded middle, in which case typical modal logics are classical and one can speak of non-classical, e.g. intuitionistic, modal logics. At any rate, "non-classical logic" is not a very descriptive term and does not at all suggest modal logic.

Comment: Hint: going on along that way, you will have $w_j \Vdash \square \lnot p$, that contradicts 2.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks Mauro ! I think I get it, I should have written step 6 as well which would have been $\neg\Diamond p$ where I would be able to reach your hint !

Comment: @DerekElkins What should I use for such a question then ? There is no non-classical logic tag ...

Comment: Your tags are fine. You can just say "modal logic". The title of the question makes it sound like you are considering a non-classical modal logic, e.g. an intuitionistic modal logic, but [that doesn't seem to be the case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_modal_logic). Ideally, you'd refer to the specific modal logic (there are *many*), e.g. [**K** or **S4**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic), and/or provide a listing of the axioms/rules of the system to make the question more self-contained. For more standard modal logics, the latter is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from $R\Diamond$ :

$$\underbrace{\Diamond A,wi}_{w_iRw_j\\A,w_j}$$

I should have written step 6 as well:

6. $\neg\Diamond p,w_j$ from $R\Diamond$ on 4

Then I could apply

7. $\Box\neg p,w_j$ from $R\neg\Diamond$ on 6
8. $w_jRw_i$ from $R_\Box$ on 7
9. $\neg p,w_i$ from $R_\Box$ on 7 and which leads to a contradiction with 1

Comment: The proof is correct; step 8 is exactly the point where *reflexivity* of $R$ is needed (see step 5).