# What does $w_i$ stands for in modal logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I want to prove that $\neg(p\rightarrow q)\neq \neg p \rightarrow q$ and I have a proof example but I have lost the first step and I don't get the following one

2. $w_iRw_i$  by hypothesis $R$ is reflexive

**I don't get this worlds $w_i$ writings, what do they stand for ?** In my last question I had a proof where in step 5, it was"choosing" a wj such that $w_iRw_j$ Does it means here that it is choosing a world where $w_iRw_i$ ?

The remaining of the question is :

3. $\Box p,w_i$ from $R_{\neg\rightarrow}$ on 1 (which is missing)
4. $\neg p,w_i$ from $R_{\neg\rightarrow}$ on 1 (which is missing)
5. $p,w_i$ from $R_\Box$ on 3 which leads to a contradiction with 4.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA quoted in full ?

Comment: Maybe you have to correct the first line of the text: "I want to prove that $\lnot (p \to q) \ne \lnot p \to q$ ...". To answer it, it is enough to use truth-table.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, indeed ! grazie mólto !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$w_i$  is a "node or world" i.e. an element of the set $W$ of the [Kripke frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Basic_definitions) $\langle W,R \rangle$ on which the so-called "accessibility relation" $R$ is defined.

The relation $R$ over $W$ is [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) iff every element of $W$ is related to itself, i.e. $w_iRw_i$ for every $w_i \in W$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! What would you guess would be step 1 ? What would have occured if we had the, maybe, "transitive" relation in step 2: i.e. $w_iRw_j$ ? When would a step $p,w_j$ and another one $\neg p, w_i$ be contadictive ?

Comment: @Marine1 - see the answer to your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561592/how-to-to-prove-that-vdash-p-rightarrow-box-diamond-p-in-a-system-where-r-i).